# How do I format SQL table queries?

Tags: sql, c

```
res = PQexec(db, "SELECT username, msg, ts, lat, lon FROM tweet");
rows = PQntuples(res);
cols = PQnfields(res);
printf("Getting %d rows\n", rows);

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
     for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      {
          msg = PQgetvalue(res, i, j);
          printf("%s\t", msg);
       }
       putchar(10);
    }

    PQclear(res);
```

.

```
username
msg
ts (lat, lon)
```

I want the printed table to be in the format I have above, but it gets printed out all on a single line. How do I add newlines and format column queries to be wrapped in parenthesis or be between commas, etc.

Comment: Show us the code that you are currently using to print.

Comment: Its not a good idea to insert formatting directives directly into the SQL query. Its best to keep a separation of concerns between the data, and how it is displayed. Better to loop through the results and add the formatting yourself

Comment: i edit to show more of the code

Comment: gilsho, when you say use a loop, do you mean i need to include the PQgetvalue method?

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `\t` to a `\n` like so

```
printf("%s\n", msg);
```

If you want to change the formatting, you can do something like this:

Assign each result to variables:

```
char *uname, *msg, *ts, *lat, *lon;
```

Then, use a temporary:

```
char *res = malloc(/*pick a safe size*/);
sprintf(res, "%s\n%s\n%s (%s, %s)\n", uname, msg, ts, lat, lon);
printf(res);
```

Alternatively, you can skip the assigning to res and use

```
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s (%s, %s)\n", uname, msg, ts, lat, lon);
```

instead

Comment: ts is type "timestamp" what % would i use for that?

Comment: all of them are returned as `%s` (string)